# ios: Share Extension does not allow me to share .txt or .csv file to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, share-extension

I have a share extension in my app. It does share photos from photos app and .pdf files from files app. But it does not work on .txt or .csv files. What do I have to do to allow it?

Comment: Could you share the code to read txt or csv file in  Share Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found by accident that in order to work with these text files, you have to add to plist of your extension `NSExtensionActivationSupportsText` than your app will popup in list of available apps to share into

[image]